# Dart sourcemaps for packaged app

Tags: google-chrome, dart, source-maps

I'm having problem with getting source maps running when my app is packaged as a chrome app.
(I cannot see any dart files in Chrome developer tools). Is this feature currently supported?

When running the page as is, not as packaged app, the source map works fine.

I managed to get this working for unpacked extension, by changing the sourcemapingURL in the generated js file to absolute path:

```
//@ sourceMappingURL=file:///ABSOLUTE_PATH.js.map
```

I wonder if this can be done for packaged application.

Comment: This is really annoying. I tried searching all around the net for a solution to this problem. If there were only a way to relax CSP for packaged apps for debugging purposes, then this would be possible. I'm not sure what we're supposed to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works in SDK 0.7.1 the build is run via build.dart

```
#!/usr/bin/env dart

import 'dart:io';
import 'package:polymer/component_build.dart';
import 'package:polymer/deploy.dart' as deploy;

void main() {
  build(new Options().arguments, ['web/FlashCards.html'])
    .then((_) => deploy.main());
}
```